# How to make a html5 game as apk file in android

Tags: android, html

I have done a HTML5 game and now I want to package the game into an apk file in Android.

How can I achieve this in Android?

Comment: Maybe have a look at http://phonegap.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `WebView` should solve your problem. This might look simple but in my opinion it is the effective solution if you are thinking to implement any HTML/JavaScript trick in an android device.

Answer (score 1):

`Webview` is a `ViewGroup` in android. you can create a instance and add it to any hierarchy.

```
WebView webview = new WebView(this);
setContentView(webview);
webview.loadUrl("http://google.com/");
```